# Smelly shower drain

Tags: shower

My shower drains like it should.
The problem is it has water standing in the drain.
I cleaned the drain but, nothing seems to be in the drain.
The water is stagnant and smelly.
I tried vinegar and baking soda too.  I do not want to use bleach.
Any suggestions??

Comment: Hi Linda, some pictures would help.  Do you have access under the shower, in the basement, perhaps?

Comment: Is it used regularly? Has the water level changed recently?